# iOS Missing Required Icon File when uploading to App Store

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I've build an iOS app using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), and then eventually used [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com) to package the app. However when I try and upload the app to the App Store I get the following errors:

[image]

Firstly I don't understand what the first error is implying, there is an icon.png file. Also, the other images are also contained in the package. This is my config.xml file where I define the icons:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-57.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-120.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-152.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@3x.png"/>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Few things might help: file path should be `resources/ios/icon/icon.png` not `resources\ios\icon\icon.png`, also does that path exist in the ZIP or repo you are sending to PhoneGapBuild? Additionally, you should have a default icon set as `<icon src="icon.png" />` (and in the base path) as defined in the PhoneGapBuild docs. See if any of those help

Comment: I agree with Dawson.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue, and fixed it by doing this:

1. Went to the main folder of my ionic project
2. Ran  "ionic resources"
3. Ran "ionic build ios --release"
4. On XCode: Archive
5. From Organizer: Upload to App store

Answer (score 0):

After running `ionic cordova resources` and `ionic cordova build ios --release`, I had to manually copy images from

- from /resources/ios/icon/ to /platforms/ios/project_name/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
- from /resources/ios/splash/ to /platforms/ios/project_name/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/

This is best done before opening Xcode. Sometimes it's necessary to remove and re-add the whole platform before starting over with the above.